# Wi-Fi not working on Kali Linux (Macbook Pro 13, Mid 2014)

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, macintosh

I have successfully created Live USB with Kali Linux and booted up on my Macbook Pro 13, Mid 2014. Everything works perfect, except one thing: my internal wireless card isn't detected by Kali, thus I cannot connect to Wi-Fi.

Have gone through these manuals:

- https://pentestmac.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/kali-linux-broadcom-wireless-on-macbook/
- https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?25240-Macbook-Pro-Kali-Mac-OS-Dual-Boot-Install-Guide-amp-WiFi-Guide

everything goes well, but fails on last command, which is "modprobe wl". I get this error: FATAL: Module wl not found.

Somebody has experience with it, is it possible to detect internal wireless card on Mac in Kali Linux, or do I have to buy an external USB wireless adapter?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: How about `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic && sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`?

Comment: after first one, i recieve: E: Package 'linux-headers-generic' has no installation candidate
after second one: E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source; should I paste you whole output after running these?

Answer (score 1):

Try this link very useful has a read me. This is to install the b43 drivers for Broadcom wireless cards, which is what your Mac should have, so it can be recognised by Kali - the reason they aren't installed is because the native drivers are actually for Atheros and Realtek, more widely used in other PC's - https://gregoryconrad.github.io/downloads/wifi_on_kali.zip

Click on the link, and a download should take place, then open the readme, and it should be quite clear - But in short, you will need to put the drivers on an external usb and then boot into kali and install them.
This worked for me, hopefully it does for you!

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/185329)

Comment: sorry about that @JeffSchaller

Comment: No problem! Everyone learns the site for the first time at some point! Welcome to U&L!